# Why does installing 11.10 or 12.04 on old laptops fail?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, installation, hardware, laptop

I recently reimaged my Lenovo t400 with Ubuntu. However, after wiping two other systems (Compaq Presario 2100 and Dell Latitude D600) both Ubuntu 11.10 and Ubuntu 12.04 fail to load on boot.  I am concerned that there is some type of issue using Ubuntu on these older systems as every part of the process has been repeated/attempted several times in the same manner as practiced in the successful load of the newer Lenovo t400.

I now have two laptops without an operating system as the discs/thumb drives that were formatted to load on these devices do not seem to work. I would appreciate any assistance that you may be able to provide.

Comment: And that same procedure would be what?.. and what are the specs of those old laptops, do any errors come up? add it to your question.

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "fail to load on boot?"  Does it read the CD at all?  Or does it run from the CD, but fail after the installation?  If it runs from the LiveCD, that would be meaningful.

Comment: The question should read "on *these particular* old laptops fail"...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried burning the OS that your trying to install on a CD and insert it in Laptop drive and boot from disk?

Comment: This is not an answer; it's not even a wrong answer; it is a question.

Comment: yes, i have tried to burn to multiple CDs as well as boot from a jump drive.  The older laptops do not seem to recognize the os on boot despite the fact that I manually go in to prioritize the CD/thumb drive in terms of boot order.  The newer lenovo had no problem which leads me to believe there is something about these older units (early 2000's) that prevents them from recognizing unbuntu OS on load.  It is perplexing.

Comment: Hi Marty, can you clarify?

Comment: Are you saying it tries to boot from CD but fails?  I suppose it's possible that it simply will not work, but that would be unusual.

Comment: that is exactly what i am saying.  and to reiterate on whether the disc/drive is formatted incorrectly - I've successfully booted and loaded the OS on another machine, however, it was much newer than the two that do not seem to work.  I am not sure what this issue is but the older machines do not like unbuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Adam for the Dell press F2 and enter BIOS after power on - look at the post settings and verify that USB emulation is enabled; if you are booting from USB drive.  I tried to post a screen shot but was not able. 
If you want to boot from CD on the Dell press F12 shortly after power on and use arrow keys to select boot drive, then press enter.